# How to generate a **uid** whenever a form is submitted, and want to pass it in every form I made to update specific user results

Tags: forms

I have created a form with the menu item url like this.

```
$items['/component'] = array(
    'title' => 'Component',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
     ....
);
```

my form structure is so,mething like this:

```
function _my_component_add_form($form, &$form_state) {
$cid = "";
$form['id'] = array(
        '#type' => 'hidden',
        '#value' => $cid,
    );
$form['human_name'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Component name'),
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#size' => 32,
    '#maxlength' => 255,
  );
  ......
```

now when I submit this form, I see **form['id'] = blank**

Now, what I want is, when I submit my result my url should become like

> admin/component/1

I have made anotjher url to show results.
Its url become `/component/show`
But I have given edit/delete links in front of every submitted entry, so user can edit and delete too.

My Question is I want to generate a **uid** whenever a form is submitted, and want to pass it in every form I made in my module, so each and every form has a parameter "uid". and form will work for specific user who only submits his form.

Say, If I want to update his submitted results, I need an ID of that user, so that no other user submissions will get updated.

Hope, I am able to express my confusion for "UID".

Comment: is it a Unique ID or a User ID you're trying to create ?

Comment: Really hard to understand the question. Can you tell us what it is you're trying to achieve? Is it form security to prevent it from being tampered with between submissions? Or do you just simply want the current user's ID who's trying to process the forms?

Comment: current user's ID who's trying to process the forms

Comment: when I am creating form my url is admin/component. But when I submit form I want it to become admin/component/1     where "1" is current user's ID who's trying to process the forms

Comment: for ref: https://www.drupal.org/node/290462 like /drupal/show_my_content_page/$id

Answer (score -1):

suggestion : First of all never use 'id' as id in any drupal form or anywhere.

set "global $user;"
$user_uid = $user->uid;

set your URL like

['admin/component/'.$user_id]